# Ajax vanilla Js sent post request is showing a blank body

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I'm trying to print the data which has been received at the server side but it always
shows a blank body output printing `req={}`

I've been trying for days and I can't find the answer, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

the server side code:

```
const express= require('express');
const app=express();

const data_itself = require('./data.js');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.listen(3100,()=>{
   console.log('sever listening at port 3100...')
});
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views','public');

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
   res.redirect('/home');
});

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
   var random_data='recived post request!'
   res.send(random_data);
   console.log('req=',req.body); //this outputs to req={}
});
```

The client side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Sample Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="send_info()">Submit data</button>
    <div id="stat"></div>
</body>
<script>
    data=['xyz'];
        function send_info(){
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML =
             this.responseText;
           }
          };
           xhr.open("POST",'/', true);
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
           xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    
        }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You use the `urlencoded` body parser but send json data. choose one or the other (or use both body parsers)

Comment: You're sending JSON to express but never [set up express to parse JSON](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserjsonoptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your express server use the JSON parser middleware. Add the following line to your server file.

```
app.use(express.json())
```

An explanation of the middleware is available at this link: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html